# Can't access ListView or LinearLayout from Resource.Id

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

In Xamarin.Android I'm just following a tutorial, it has an axml layout as follows:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="This app (sort of) was developed (sort of) by its developer (sort of), anything else?"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Here is a quick"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    <Button
        android:text="OK Whatever"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/OKWhatever" />
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myListView" /> //  *TLDR*  <====
</LinearLayout>
```

But when I try to access the list view by typing:

```
 listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myListView);
```

I get a 'Resource.Id does not have a definition of myListView, even though I get intellisense of other types like buttons and text views in the same XML.
Is it something about LinearLayout and ListView? if so why is it written this way in the tutorial?

Comment: xamarin doesnt show you error on your xml layout?

Comment: No, I guess the Resource.Designer.cs is not updating for some reason. But LinearLayout was never accessible anyway.

Comment: is the build action of the xml set to Android Resource?is this an activity or a fragment?

Comment: Is the type myListView defined in your `Resource.designer.cs`?

Comment: 1-Yes of course the build setting is set to Android Resource. 2-It's an activity. @JonDouglas No! I think that's the problem, Resource.Designer.cs is acting wierd 'again'.

Comment: Intellisense doesn't update automatically - you need to build before it will update.  Also if you are using Resharper it can completely fail for all resources and only re-opening VS can fix it.

Comment: @JonneyShih It should regenerate. Just ensure you have "Show All Files" as it does not re-include the file and it might be hidden. You can then right click it and "Include in Project"

Comment: @JonDouglas Where do I check "Show All Files"? If you mean "Open Folder in File Explorer" I did that and it's not showing.

Comment: @JonneyShih http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2009/09/14/visual-studio-tip-show-all-file/ for VS, otherwise you have to right click your project -> options -> show all files in Xamarin Studio

Answer (score 1):

You have `android:id="@@+id/myListView"` instead of `android:id="@+id/myListView"` in your layout which is probably causing it not to generate the corresponding resource id.

Comment: No that's not it, that was typo, I fixed it but it's still not working.

Comment: @JonneyShih: Try commenting the line that isn't compiling, compile the project and see if the property gets generated.

Comment: The problem is Resource.Designer.cs isn't updating, I deleted it but Xamarin is not regenerating it, I think I'm stuck.

Comment: If you delete the designer file and rebuild the project it will generate a new file, but you then need to manually add that file back into the project.